# Understanding individual users over multiple username changes using username change records only (no unique ID exists)

Tags: algorithm, python-3.x, data-structures

I have a graph theory problem which involves analysing users over multiple username changes (a unique ID for each user has not been kept unfortunately).

There is a list of username changes and the time during which that username was changed. The format is: `'2017-01-01 02:00:00', 'previous_username', 'new_username'`.

The objective is to link each user's most up to date username for a given point in time. For example, I would like to be able to answer the question: what is the current username of the user who had the username `'previous_username'` on `'2016-12-31 00:00:00'`?

I recognise that this is a graph theory problem and I am looking for solve it in python. Please note that user's might have changed their usernames multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is not graph theory problem. You are looking for data structure that can provide queries about usernames. To have fast implementation of searches of this kind, some indexing is needed.
A simple solution is to have data structure that:

- for each user stores list of it's past usernames with time duration when username was used,
- maps every used username to list of positions where it is used in user lists.

With that index in user list is user's unique ID.

Something like this (not tested at all):

```
from collections import defaultdict

class LogData:
  def __init__(self):
    self.users = []
    self.usernames = defaultdict(list)

  # Note: data should be filled in time sorted order!
  def add(self, previous_username, new_username, time):
    # Find is username know
    for i, username_list in enumerate(self.users):
      if username_list[-1]['username'] == previous_username:
        username_list[-1]['to_time'] = time
        self.usernames[new_username].append((i, len(username_list)))
        username_list.append(dict(username=new_username, from_time=time))
        return
    # First apearance of previous_username
    self.usernames[previous_username].append((len(self.users), 0))
    self.usernames[new_username].append((len(self.users), 1))
    self.users.append([
      dict(username=previous_username, to_time=time),
      dict(username=new_username, from_time=time),
    ])

  def current_username(self, username, time):
    for user_ind, i in self.usernames.get(username, []):
      d = self.users[user_ind][i]
      from_time = d.get('from_time')
      to_time = d.get('to_time')
      if (from_time is None or from_time <= time) and \
         (to_time is None or to_time >= time):
        return self.users[user_ind][-1]['username']
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could see this is a graph theory problem. But I think the easiest way is to first order the list - let's call it `username_changes` - by time, and then traverse it similar to this example (haven't tested t

```
username_changes.sort(key = lambda x: x[0])
from_time = '2016-12-31 00:00:00'
user_name = 'previous_username'
for row in username_changes:
    if row[0] >= from_time and row[1]==user_name:
        user_name = row[2]
print(user_name)
```

Comment: How does this solution take into consideration multiple unique users?